# regex (or other way) to find numbers followed by a space

Tags: awk, sed, regular-expression, numeric-data

I'm running the following

`awk '$2 ~ /^[0-9]\s+/ {print($2)}' file >> file1`

Not sure how to correct this to only select lines where digits are followed by a space?

Comment: [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 3):

Your pattern will never match because it's looking for a space in field two, but as fields are separated by spaces these characters can never be in a field.

If you're looking for field two to contain only digits, you can use this

```
$2 ~ /^[[:digit:]]+$/
```

If you want to guarantee it has space following it, you can check that field three is non-zero

```
$2 ~ /^[[:digit:]]+$/ && $3 > ""
```